# How to intersect 5 sql queries that do not belong to same table and have millions of data as output for each query

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

How to intersect 5 SQL queries that do not belong to same table and have millions of data as output for each query?

I want to find out data that is present in all the five queries output.

Answer (score 1):

You can intersect them, as you said (all statements have to have equal number of columns and they have to match in datatype), e.g.

```
SQL> select empno, ename from emp
  2  intersect
  3  select deptno, loc  from dept;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

---

Or, you can use each query as a CTE and then join them (result will return rows that *match*):

```
SQL> with
  2  q1 (valn, valc) as
  3    (select empno, ename from emp),
  4  q2 (valn, valc) as
  5    (select deptno, loc  from dept)
  6  --
  7  select a.valn
  8  from q1 a join q2 b on a.valn = b.valn and a.valc = b.valc;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

---

Millions of rows? It'll probably take time to get the result, I presume.